# Open existing HERE Map zoomed, in modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, here-api

I am looking to open an existing HERE map in a modal - zoomed in and larger.

When I do this inline within the same 'map' element, it works fine.

For instance:
let's say
$('#map') contains  my map.

```
<!-- HTML: -->
<!--My modal has an element that the map should be copied into -->
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div id="map-zoomed">MAP!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div id="map">Initial Rendered here in a small container of fixed width/height</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Open Larger Map</button>
 <div id="map-zoomed-inline">Inline map - same issue</div>

// My JS:
$('.btn').click(event => {            
           $('#myLargeModalLabel').modal('hide');
            // Ideally would have set the #map-zoomed element, but I do this instead: 
           $('#map').attr('style','width: 100vw; height: 100vh');
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 0.5, true);
            map.getViewPort().resize();
            // the original map element shows the updated map just fine.

            
            let newMap = $('#map').clone();
            // $('#map-zoomed-inline').html(newMap);  // Did this outside a modal, and have the same issue.

            $('#map-zoomed').html(newMap);  // This works, but the map needs to be 'resized' here - how?
            $('#map').hide();
            $('#myLargeModalLabel').modal('show');  // How to ensure the modal shows the entire map without cropping it out?
        
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to show a map in some new html element container then you need **always** to initialize a new Map object like in this snippet of code:

```
// set up containers for the map

var mapContainer = document.createElement('div');
var staticMapContainer = document.createElement('div');

mapContainer.style.height = '300px';

staticMapContainer.style.position = 'absolute';
staticMapContainer.style.width = '600px';
staticMapContainer.style.height = '300px';

document.getElementById('map').appendChild(mapContainer);
document.getElementById('panel').appendChild(staticMapContainer);

// initialize a map, this map is interactive
var map = new H.Map(mapContainer,
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,{
  center: {lat: 53.430, lng: -2.961},
  zoom: 7,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

// initialize a map that will be synchronised
var staticMap = new H.Map(staticMapContainer,
  defaultLayersSync.vector.normal.map,{
  center: {lat: 53.430, lng: -2.961},
  zoom: 7,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
```

The full code of above example see please on https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/maps/synchronising-two-maps

The cloning map container element or similar Dom manipulation will not work.